# SSL read timeout trying to list VSIs in datacenter

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I should explain a little history. At one time I as issuing the http:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?    objectMask=mask[datacenter.name,status,globalIdentifier,primaryBackendIpAddress,primaryIpAddress,billingItem.categoryCode,billingItem.description,billingItem.createDate,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.username,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.email,users.username,users.email,users.userStatus,operatingSystemReferenceCode,softwareComponents.passwords,operatingSystem,hourlyBillingFlag,localDiskFlag,managedResourceFlag,privateNetworkOnlyFlag,powerState,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.name,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.id;blockDevices.diskImage,networkVlans,activeTransactionCount,activeTransactions,consoleIpAddressRecord.type,consoleIpAddressRecord.port,consoleIpAddressRecord.ipAddress.ipAddress]
```

This retrieved all VSI's in all datacenters and I started getting this same error every time so I now loop through each SoftLayer datacenter get the VSI's. I am using the following EST API:

```
 https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?objectMask=mask[datacenter.name,status,globalIdentifier,primaryBackendIpAddress,primaryIpAddress,billingItem.categoryCode,billingItem.description,billingItem.createDate,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.username,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.email,users.username,users.email,users.userStatus,operatingSystemReferenceCode,softwareComponents.passwords,operatingSystem,hourlyBillingFlag,localDiskFlag,managedResourceFlag,privateNetworkOnlyFlag,powerState,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.name,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.id;blockDevices.diskImage,networkVlans,activeTransactionCount,activeTransactions,consoleIpAddressRecord.type,consoleIpAddressRecord.port,consoleIpAddressRecord.ipAddress.ipAddress]&objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"_=sjc01"}}}}
```

All works fine except I am getting:

```
'_content' => '500 SSL read timeout:
',
'_rc' => 500,
'_headers' => bless( {
'client-warning' => 'Internal response',
'client-date' => 'Mon, 07 Mar 2016 16:23:33 GMT',
'content-type' => 'text/plain'
}, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
'_msg' => 'SSL read timeout: ',
```

This error happens on the SJC01 and TOR01 SoftLayer datacenters. Why is this timeout occurring.

Notice the works on other datacenters in this loop, but fails on SJC01 and TOR01.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your objectMask, you are fetching a large amount of data from the softlayer database and that causes the fail,  you can try using limits see information about that here http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Rest

if that does not work you will need to break your object mask down in parts e.g. you use a request to fetch some properties using a object mask with a few properties, then another request to fetch other properties and so on until you have all the properties you wish.

Regards

Comment: Thank you.  I am looking at resultLimit now.

Comment: If I specify resultLimit and objeckMask together the objectMask is being ignored. as an example.        https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?resultLimit=300,100?objectMask=mask[datacenter,status,    There are more objectMask values and not all are returned as they were before I added resultLimit

Comment: to mix the result limit and object mask you need to use & instead ? e.g.SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?resultLimit=10,20&objectMask=mask[id,datacenter]

Comment: Thank you,  yeah, found that out myself.   dddduuuuuhhh    :-)